# Golang GORM invalid association

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to write a very simple belongsTo association with GORM, but with primary keys that isn't Id.

My structs are as such:

```
type State struct {
    FIPS string `gorm:"type:char(2);primary_key;column:FIPS"`
    Name string `gorm:"not null"`
    Area float64 `gorm:"type:real;not null"`
}

type ZipCode struct {
    ZipCode   string `gorm:"type:char(5);primary_key;"`
    Name      string `gorm:"not null"`
    State     State `gorm:"ForeignKey:StateFIPS;AssociationForeignKey:FIPS"`
    StateFIPS string `gorm:"type:char(2);column:state_FIPS;not null"`
}
```

and with the following code:

```
var zc ZipCode
var s State
db.Model(&zc).Related(&s)
```

I get the error: `[2017-05-18 14:26:13]  invalid association []` and a find on the zipcode doesn't load the state. Does GORM not like non-Id primary keys or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code :

```
var zc ZipCode
var s State
db.Model(&zc).Related(&s)
```

You are not set anything to your `zc` variable. so that's why you get an error of  `invalid association []` with an empty data.

To fix this you must get the ZipCode data from your database like :

```
db.First(&zc, 1) // find ZipCode with id 1.
```

and then you can associate your `zc` full code would be :

```
var zc ZipCode
var s State

db.First(&zc, 1) // find ZipCode with id 1.
db.Model(&zc).Related(&s)
```

Note : I'm not testing this actual code but I think it would fix the problem.

Comment: The user was specifically asking how to query on his index that isn't ID. This solution works, but doesn't solve the problem. I've been reading http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#many-to-many and https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html to try to figure out how you're supposed to do this, but I'm stuck myself.